# POST becomes GET after ProxyPass

Tags: node.js, apache, express, postman

I have a nodejs app running inside a docker container on port 3050.  If I allow the port through the firewall then everything works fine.  But if I try to ProxyPass it then the app seems to receive GET instead of POST.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3050/
```

When I look at the access log apache receives the request as a POST.  But logging the req.method in expressjs results in GET.  I have also tried loads of other settings

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3050/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3050/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

The strangest thing is that I am Proxying lots of other services like gitlab and keycloak without any problem.

Could it be something to do with HTTP 1.1 or HTTP 2?  Or does my httpd server have some setting messed up?

Answer (score 0):

I was only testing with postman...obviously in future I should try curl or something as well.  Turns out that postman has a setting "Redirect with the original HTTP method instead of the default behavior of redirecting with GET." which is turned off by default.  I don't know whether the browser will behave like this but at least now it seems to be working

**update:**
Actually it wasn't even that setting.  it was because i had not prefixed the url with https:// due to a training course which excluded the protocol because we weren't working with secure. so the httpd server proxied port 80 to 443 and postman didn't handle it correct.  as i would be hitting directly https in production it shouldn't be a problem